# ocaml says there is a syntax error in the expression supposed to be run in camllight

Tags: ocaml, ml, caml-light

I'm following this paper: [Introduction to Functional Programming](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/Lectures/funprog-jrh-1996/all.pdf). In the chapter on the ML language family there are examples to be run with `camllight`. However, in Debian repositories, I haven't found any package that contains `camllight`, so I'm using `ocaml` instead:

```
$ ocaml
    OCaml version 4.01.0
```

Example code from the paper worked fine until this one from the part on custom type definitions:

```
#type ('a,'b)sum = inl of 'a | inr of 'b;;
```

Trying this one out with `ocaml` outputs:

```
# type ('a,'b)sum = inl of 'a | inr of 'b;;
Error: Syntax error
```

with the first `of` underlined.

Why the syntax error?  Is this some language feature of `camllight` that is not present in `ocaml`? Or can I enable it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
# type ('a,'b)sum = Inl of 'a | Inr of 'b;;
```

In OCaml you need to capitalize the first letter of your constructor.

Edit1: Also I noticed in the paper you linked he latter has his first letters uppercased for his constructors. I also noticed in the caml light docs they also use that same notation. <s>So maybe it's a mistake in the paper?</s>

Edit2: I ended up installing caml light, and it appears that in caml light that capitalizing the first letter does not matter. Unlike OCaml either way is fine.